# Use the host's environment variables as chef attributes (vagrant) - how to manage passwords?

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, vagrant

On a host machine, I have sth like:

```
export SOME_USER=foo
export SOME_PASSWORD=password
```

I want to turn some of the host machine's environment variables into attributes in an attributes/default.rb:

```
user = ENV["SOME_USER"]
password = ENV["SOME_PASSWORD"]
node.default["some"]["url"] = "http://#{user}:#{password} ..."
```

But, `ENV` here is the guest os's `ENV`. Can I access my host's environment in an attributes file?

More broadly, what is the preferred way to define a user/password in chef without checking passwords in anywhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to do this is with encrypted databags.

Basically, you store the values on the chef server, encrypted with a key. You give this key to the nodes that need the values, and they can download and decrypt the values, getting the passwords. This not only prevents checking in plain text passwords, but ensures the passwords are encrypted on the wire as well.

Read more about it: http://wiki.opscode.com/display/chef/Encrypted+Data+Bags

Comment: I don't like the solution and I don't use chef anymore ATM. But, it looks like this would have been the way to go .. hrmph ...